# error executing a query with date check in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table with year and month values saved as int datatype columns [Year] and [Month] correspondingly. I need to query the table limiting the output by a certain date using WHERE clause. I came up with a solution using DATEFROMPARTS function (avoids multiple conversions of datatypes), which works perfectly in the SELECT clause (the number of distinct dates is limited so I can check all of them), but fails when I am trying to use the composite date in a WHERE clause.

Thus query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) FROM MyTable
```

gives

```
2019-04-01
2019-05-01
2019-06-01
2019-07-01
2019-08-01
2019-09-01
2019-10-01
2019-11-01
2019-12-01
2020-01-01
2020-02-01
2020-03-01
```

but when I add a WHERE clause like

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) < convert(date, getdate(), 23)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [MonthNumber], 1) < convert (date, '2019-12-01', 23)
```

I get an error:

> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

I am using SQL Server Ver. 13

**DISCLAIMER**
The data is stored on a remote SQL server I am accessing from a cloud machine. It is a view, I have zero permissions on, only to read and use it further in an ETL process. There are **no** illegal values in Year and Month columns like NULL, Month > 12, etc.

**UPDATE**
I have tried a similar scenario on an SQL Server 2016:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL)

INSERT INTO MyTable
           ([Year], [Month])
     VALUES
          (2019, 9)
         ,(2019, 10)
         ,(2019, 11)
         ,(2019, 12)
         ,(2020, 1)
         ,(2020, 2)
         ,(2020, 3)
         ,(2020, 4)
```

A combination of DATEFROMPARTS or concatenating dateparts and converting to date of different formats does not work, at the best, the date only looks ok with yyyy-mm-dd format, but fails to compare with a getdate() function.

The Solution suggested by @John-Cappelletti helped to solve the initial problem:

```
try_convert(date, concat([Year],'/',[Month],'/', 1))
```

although it still unclear to me why it is not possible to convert the combined date into different date styles.

Comment: I *assume* By SQL Server Version 13, you mean SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample data that replicates the problem, please?

Comment: Based on the ***assumed*** sample data, I can't replicate your problem. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf18f61f4a6000114ce449a2a666dac7)

Comment: in which form do you want the data?

Comment: DDL and DML would be best, tabular formatted `text` if not.

Comment: I just found out that none of my date conversions work. e.g. 
convert(date, convert(nvarchar(4), [Year])+ Right('0' + convert(nvarchar(2), [MonthNumber]),2) + '01', 104) still gives yyyy-mm-dd instead of expected dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: INSERT INTO MyTable
           ([Year]
           ,[Month]
           ,[WeekNumber]
           ,[ProductCode]
)
     VALUES
           (<Year, int,>
           ,<Month, int,>
           ,<WeekNumber, int,>
           ,<ProductCode, nvarchar(255),>
)
GO

Comment: [edit] your question, don't put it in the comments where it's very hard to consume,/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a data issue, perhaps use `try_convert()` with a `concat()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Year] int,[Month] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (2020,1)
,(2020,1)
,(2020,2)
,(2020,222)

Select * 
      ,try_convert(date,concat([Year],'/',[Month],'/', 1))
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Year    Month   (No column name)
2020    1       2020-01-01
2020    1       2020-01-01
2020    2       2020-02-01
2020    222     NULL          << There's a problem
```

Comment: Thanks, your conversion method worked in the end. Although I don't have any illegal year or month values as in your example. And I still do not understand why it does not work with other datepart separators like '-' and even with '/' does not convert to dates of a certain format (e.g. 112 or 104).

Comment: @user12197757 Always happy to help.  Could be NULLS or strings (with trailing spaces)?  The important thing is to convert it into a date, then you could apply a desired format if needed  :)

Comment: both columns are defined as int. inspection with DISTINCT did not reveal any NULLS or months > 12

Comment: @user12197757 Bogus years ?  That is the only thing left :)

Answer (score 1):

Leave off the `23`:

```
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) < convert(date, getdate())
```

You probably have an issue with the internationalization settings.  Your version is converting `getdate()` to a string and back to a date.

Comment: The 23 style code shouldn't have any effect. A Style code is effectively ignored when you aren't converting from or to a `(n)varchar`. As the OP is converting from a `datetime` to a `date` it won't do anything. For both `CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),23)` and `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` I get the result `2020-03-12`. The error the OP has, as well, is specific to `DATEFROMPARTS`, not `CONVERT`.

Comment: getdate() returns the date in the same format: 2020-03-12 18:23:49.640
in addition, I tried an explicit type conversion on the both sides of < sign, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

`DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR,MONTH,DAY)` will return a value in a `DATE` format.

Simply `CAST` the parameter you're wanting to compare it to in the same format. Then are you comparing the same type of formats.

The error you've previously got is because you're trying to convert to different data types.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```